# Attaching data to different views when dragged

Tags: android

I have multiple views being dragged around, each representing an emotion. the idea is to have each view send an entry to a database that varies based on what view is dragged.

the views are created here:

```
_root = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.root);

_view = new ImageView(this);
_view.setImageResource(R.drawable.smile); 
_view2 = new ImageView(this);
_view2.setImageResource(R.drawable.frown); 



RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150, 50);
layoutParams.leftMargin = 250;
layoutParams.topMargin = 250;
layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
_view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
_view.setOnTouchListener(this);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150, 50);
layoutParams2.leftMargin = 250;
layoutParams2.topMargin = 500;
layoutParams2.bottomMargin = -250;
layoutParams2.rightMargin = -250;
_view2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
_view2.setOnTouchListener(this);
_root.addView(_view);
_root.addView(_view2);

}
```

And the movement and drag is defined here:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
            _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:  
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Exit_Activity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
            layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
            layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
            layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            break;
    }
    _root.invalidate();
    return true;
}

}
```

As you can see, ACTION_UP currently sends the user to the next activity, regardless of which view is dragged. What's the best way to have the app differentiate between views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set ID for the individual view. Retrieve the ID when the view is clicked. [ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) is unique identity for each view. To set the id:

```
view.setId(x);
```

When clicked, retrieve the id:

```
id = view.getId();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, just wondering if I should use an if statement to define the action taken based on the id retrieved, or if there is a more eloquent way of doing so. Thanks again.